# Django Channels - Receive JSON objects

Tags: python, json, django, webrtc

for a `WebRTC` project, I have to build up a signaling mechanism. I use `Django Channels` for that job. As you might know in `WebRTC`, there are `Session Description` objects that will be passed back and forth as "offer"/"answer" and also there are `ICE candidate` objects which will also be passed between two (or more) clients.
Playing with `Django Channels` a little bit, I have wrote the following consumer:

```
'''
A basic consumer that accepts WebSocket connections on the path
/ws/chat/ROOM_NAME/ that takes any message it receives on the
WebSocket and echos it back to the same WebSocket.

we want to have multiple instances of SignallingConsumer in the same room communicate
with each other. To do that we will have each SignallingConsumer add its channel
to a group whose name is based on the room name. That will allow SignallingConsumers
to transmit messages to all other SignallingConsumers in the same room.
'''
class SignallingConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        print("connect() is called.")

        '''
        Obtains the 'room_name' parameter from the URL route in chat/routing.py
        that opened the WebSocket connection to the consumer.
        Every consumer has a scope that contains information about its connection,
        including in particular any positional or keyword arguments from the URL route
        and the currently authenticated user if any.
        '''
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']

        '''
        Constructs a Channels group name directly from the user-specified room name,
        without any quoting or escaping.
        Group names may only contain letters, digits, hyphens, and periods.
        Therefore this example code will fail on room names that have other characters.
        '''
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name



        '''
        Join room group by adding the channel name to the group.
        The async_to_sync(…) wrapper is required because ChatConsumer is a synchronous
        WebsocketConsumer but it is calling an asynchronous channel layer method.
        (All channel layer methods are asynchronous.)
        Group names are restricted to ASCII alphanumerics, hyphens, and periods only.
        Since this code constructs a group name directly from the room name, it will
        fail if the room name contains any characters that aren’t valid in a group
        name.
        '''
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )


        '''
        Accepts the WebSocket connection.
        If you do not call accept() within the connect() method then the
        connection will be rejected and closed. You might want to reject a
        connection for example because the requesting user is not authorized
        to perform the requested action.
        It is recommended that accept() be called as the last action
        in connect() if you choose to accept the connection.
        '''
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print("disconnect() is called.")

        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    # text_data is of type String 
    def receive(self, text_data):
        print("Received data: " + text_data)

        # json.loads(): takes in a String and returns a JSON object
        # text_data_json is of type JSONObject
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'offer_answer_message',
                    'data': text_data_json
                }
        )


    def offer_answer_message(self, event):
        # we access the JSONObject via event['data'] and
        # store it into data variable
        data = event['data']


        # json.dumps(): takes in a JSONObject and returns a String
        self.send(json.dumps(data))
```

The comments are basically for myself. I have tweaked the code from the official site of `Django Channels` a little bit for my purpose. For my question, the `receive()` method is very important. The questions regarding this are the following ones:

1. So, what the consumer should do is to pass the offer (or answer)
   from client A ( or client B ) to the other remote peer. Does this
   work here ?
2. Also, the `ICE candidates` which contain the network information about a peer
   should also be passed to the remote peer. Does this work here ?
3. The `receive()` method takes a String as parameter. For that reason, I have to convert my `JSON` objects to Strings on the client side before sending them. I don't like that solution. What I would rather do is passing the `JSON` objects directly to the `receive()` method on the server side. How I would do it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can receive a offer or answer using this receive method say one is a host other is peer, you have already made a group... so just forward offer/answer accordingly to required consumer, keep track what type of message it is i.e. its a offer / answer.
2. Similarly when ever you set the remote description or the local description on client side a event `onicecandidate` must be handled by sending the candidate information to other client just like offer and answer..

> `PC.onicecandidate = (event)=>{
>           if(iceCand){
>               await Socket.send(JSON.stringify({
>                  "who" : "user1",
>                   "for" : "user2",
>                   "candidate" : event.candidate
>               }));
>           }
>       };`

3. You need to get it via JSON ... otherwise you get a no data for the candidate key in dict given in code above.. but for `AsyncConsumer` or `SyncConsumer` the receive method takes in a dict as far as I know, dict like given below:

> `event = {"type" : "websocket.receive", "text" : data}`